# CloudFormation: stack is stuck, CloudTrail events shows repeating DeleteNetworkInterface event

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

I am deploying a stack with CDK. It gets stuck in `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`. CloudTrail logs show repeating events in logs:

`DeleteNetworkInterface`
`CreateLogStream`

What should I look at next to continue debugging? Is there a known reason for this to happen?

[image]

Comment: What's the CloudFormation event that it gets stuck on? Are you able to isolate the CDK code that results in this behavior?

Comment: It is happening on `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` creation.

Comment: How does the deployment end? It cannot continue forever, so what's the final result and/or error message?

Answer (score 2):

I also saw the exact same issue with the deployment of a CDK-based ECS/Fargate Deployment

In my instance,  I was able to diagnose the issue by following the content from the AWS support article https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-stack-stuck-progress/

What specifically diagnosed and then resolved it for me:-

- I updated my ECS service to set the [desired task count](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-ecs-service-stabilize/#Update_the_desired_count_of_the_service) of the ECS Service to 0.   At that point the Cloud Formation stack did complete successfully.
- From that, it became obvious that the actual issue was related to the creation of the initial task for my ECS Service.  I was able to diagnose that by reviewing the output in **Deployment and Events** Tab of the **ECS Service** in the **AWS Management Console**.  In my case,  the task creation was failing because of an issue with accessing the associated ECR repository.  Obviously there could be other reasons but they should show-up there.